# How to retrieve a substring after a delimiter from sql in Django?

Tags: python, sql, substring, django-orm, delimiter

How to retrieve a substring after a delimiter from sql in Django ?

For example, I have "2021-22:32" saved in my sql database. I wish to run a query which returns "32", i.e. substring after the delimiter ':'.

How can I do that in Django ?

Say my model is

```
class model(models.Model):
    str=models.CharField(max_length=25)
```

Suggest a query which returns all the entities, but with str values as explained above.

Answer (score 0):

In pure Python, you have the following options:

```py
inp = "2021-22:32"
output = inp.split(':')[1]         # 32
output = re.sub(r'^.*:', '', inp)  # 32
```

On the SQL side, you could use similar options, depending on what your particular database vendor actually is.  For instance, on Postgres you have the `SPLIT_PART` function available:

```sql
SELECT SPLIT_PART('2021-22:32', ':', 2);  -- 32
```

Comment: I'm using PostgreSQL with the Django ORM. I wish to do it using SQL queries only. Does Django ORM provide some function for this ?

Comment: @SagarAgarwal On Postgres the function you want is `SPLIT_PART`.  Most likely, Django doesn't give you access to this, and it is vendor specific.  But, you certainly could use `SPLIT_PART` as a raw query.

Comment: If not based on the delimiter, can I retrieve the substring using Substr() i.e. based on length. What would be the query in that case ?

Comment: Maybe `SUBSTRING('2021-22:32', 9, 2)` ?

Comment: In the Django ORM ?

Comment: You're asking me about a framework which you know more than I do.